# Continuous integration AND NuGet restore in VSO and Azure

Tags: azure, msbuild, nuget, azure-web-roles, build-definition

We are using VSO and Azure Cloud Services (web roles).

Previously, we have used the following `build.proj` file for our VSO build definitions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutDir>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin</OutDir>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <ProjectProperties>OutDir=$(OutDir);Configuration=$(Configuration);</ProjectProperties>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Solution Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)*.sln" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="RestorePackages">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory).nuget\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;%(Solution.Identity)&quot;" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <MSBuild Targets="Clean" Projects="@(Solution)" Properties="$(ProjectProperties)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
    <MSBuild Targets="Build" Projects="@(Solution)" Properties="$(ProjectProperties)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
    <MSBuild Targets="Rebuild" Projects="@(Solution)" Properties="$(ProjectProperties)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The reason for this is to execute NuGet restore before MSBuild began running. This is a [suggested approach](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build) by NuGet.

Now that we are trying to set up continuous integration with our Azure cloud services, as instructed in [this MSDN article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/).

This means that we must now use the `TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xml` build process template.

But when setting the template to build the `build.proj` file, the following build error occurs:

```
Exception Message: Deploying to Azure Cloud Service requires a Visual Studio Solution (.sln) that contains either a ccproj or a lsxproj. (type DeploymentException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

When using the `.sln`, all works fine.  But we obviously also need NuGet restore to occur before the build.

**What is a good solution to have both continuous integration AND NuGet restore working?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just learnt that this is redundant.  There is no reason to manually execute NuGet restore as this is already built into VSO/TFS.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037083/visualstudioonline-nuget-restore-now-built-in).