# VisualStudioOnline NuGet Restore now built in?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

Is the Host Controller on Visual Studio Online now automatically restoring NuGet package before calling MSBuild?

Previously I had to manually execute the following:

```
nuget.exe restore MySolution.sln
```

Now, when creating a new build in a new project, I noticed that I didn't need to do this.  When looking at the build logs, I see this:

[image: nuget restore command]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a change in TFS 2013 Update 2 and is reflected in VS, TFS, and VSO...